# How to add a space in hangman game

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game, where a song name is picked from a file, and the title is replaced with underscores (apart from the first letter)
However I'm not sure how to add a space into it, as some songs are more than one word, this is what I have currently:

```
def QuizStart():
    line = random.choice(open('songnamefile.txt').readlines())      
    line.split('-')
    songname, artist = line.split('-')
    underscoresong = songname
    i=0
    song_name = range(1,len(songname)) 
    for i in song_name:
        if ' ' in song_name:
            i=i+1    
        else:
            underscoresong = underscoresong.replace(songname[i],"_")
            i=i+1
    print(underscoresong, ' - ', artist)
```

Comment: Are song names saved with actual spaces?

Comment: @Dani yes they are saved in the format 'Song Name-Artist'

Comment: I’d rename them to have lower dashes instead of spaces. It’s easier to check for lower dashes than to check for spaces. Sometimes a space is referred to as “\ “, so it’s easierto rely on a simpler character, such as “_”. You can then replace those with spaces in your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to include expected output for a given input examples.

You can just multiply an array containing the placeholder character n times. e.g.:

```
songname = 'My blue submarine'

underscoresong = ''.join([songname[0]] + ['_'] * (len(songname) - 1))

print(underscoresong)
```

Output:

```
M________________
```

That will add the first character and then the underscore for as long as the songname is, minus one (for the first character). The join converts it to a string.

**Or if you want to preserve spaces:**

```
underscoresong = ''.join(
   [songname[0]] + ['_' if c != ' ' else ' ' for c in songname[1:]]
)

print(underscoresong)
```

Output:

```
M_ ____ _________
```

**Or if you want to also preserve the single quote:**

```
songname = "God's Plan-Drake"

underscoresong = ''.join(
    [songname[0]] +
    ['_' if c not in {' ', "'"} else c for c in songname[1:]]
)

print(underscoresong)
```

Output:

```
G__'_ __________
```

**You could also use regular expressions:**

```
import re

songname = "God's Plan-Drake"

underscoresong = songname[0] + re.sub(r"[^ ']", '_', songname[1:])

print(underscoresong)
```

Output:

```
G__'_ __________
```

Comment: where do i add this?

Comment: Just after you have the songname variable. You don't need the remaining code (apart from the print statement).

Comment: it gives me 'TypeError: must be str, not list'

Comment: Apologies, fixed and I added an example

Comment: this isnt quite what i was looking for, my example song will be God's Plan-Drake, when the code is run, what prints out is "G________ - Drake", when i would like it to print "G__'_ ____"

Comment: That is exactly why your question should include the sample input and expected output. I've updated my answer.